# How to use Freeform Simulated Size to change height of scrollView but not width

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I am using the `Freeform`simulated size to change the `View Controller` height so I can arrange all subviews in a `scrollview`.

- I set the height to 1200
- Add a scroll view; set the constraints to the superview
- Then add a `UIView` called `bodyView` to the `ScrollView` to be the container of the body content and set all margins to the scroll view.
- Add another `UIView` to be the header with a fixed height of 400 but set the rest of the margins to the `BodyView` to stay at the top and to be the same width.

  - Add a `UIImagevView` to the `headerView` and set all constraints to the header

This is how it looks so far:

[image]

However once the `UIViewController` is run on smaller device sizes the scroll view retains the original width of 414 and the content does not fit in the frame; even though there is no width constraint set for neither of the sub views.

Does anybody know where I am going wrong and what might be happening ?

I have been researching and even checked out other projects and cannot seem to replicate/resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bodyView must get it's width from out-side scrollview , so Control-drag from the bodyView to the viewController's view and select **Equal-Widths** -- the height is calculated according to hooked elements from top to bottom